# Necessary and Sufficient Conditions for two matrices to have the same Char Poly and Spectrum

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ , Is there any or what are the  Necessary and Sufficient Conditions so that they have same Characteristic polynomial and same set of eigenvalues. Thank you

Comment: Similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial: $A\sim B\iff P^{-1}AP=B$, thus $$\det(xI-B)=\det(xI-P^{-1}AP)=\det(xP^{-1}P-P^{-1}AP)=\\=\ldots=\det(P^{-1})\det(xI-A)\det(P)=\det(xI-A).$$

Comment: Oh! I should have mentioned I knew that condition.